# How to implement pagination along with sorting results in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I'm pretty new to Laravel, and still exploring it's features and possibilities, and I've came across a strange issue that I don't quite understand.

First of all, I'm using `Laravel 5.0` and I'm trying to make pagination of results that came from model alongside with sorting them.

Here is the code that works, but without sorting:

```
News::paginate(5);
```

And here is what I need, but doesn't work:

```
News::paginate(5)->orderByDesc('published_at');
```

I've tried doing it like so:

```
News::all()->sortByDesc('published_at')->paginate(5);
```

But then, when I call `render()` method inside view it throws error. I would like to use model's approach since it's handy and few more things depend on it, and not query builder method. Also, would like, if possible to avoid manual or any kind of custom pagination. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write this. This will solve your problem

```
News::orderBy('published_at','desc')->paginate(5);
```